# Mocha + React v.15.5.0 TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, mocha.js

I am just setting out to set up my tests since updating to `react v15.5.0` I believe that they have done a lot to bring all of the testing `in-house` as it were. So you don't need as many external sources.

however, i just can't seem to get a very simple test working.

**index.spec.js**

```
/* eslint-disable object-property-newline */
import React from 'react';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils' // ES6
import {expect} from 'chai';
import Splash from '../../../src/components/Splash';
import * as styles from '../../../src/components/Splash/style.css';


describe('<Splash />', () => {
  it('must be defined', () => {
    expect(Splash).to.be.defined;
  })

  it('should have kindred logo', () => {
    const SplashRendered = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Splash/>);
    const RenderedSplash = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(SplashRendered, styles.indexAppContent);
    expect(RenderedSplash.className).to.equal(styles.indexAppContent);
  })
});
```

**Mocha Helpers**

```
// jsdom
const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

**Splash/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from '../shared/logo/index';
import * as styles from './style.css';

class Splash extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={styles.indexAppContent}>
        <NavLink to="/home"  className={styles.index}>
          <Logo />
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Splash;
```

**Terminal**

```
> BABEL_ENV=test nyc mocha --reporter tap 'test/**/*.spec.js'

Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.
1..2
ok 1 Splash must be defined
not ok 2 Splash should have kindred logo
  TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
      at _classCallCheck (/var/www/kindred.com/src/components/Splash/index.js:1:10298)
      at Splash (/var/www/kindred.com/src/components/Splash/index.js:1:10514)
```

I believe I am missing a fundimental part of testing app. I believed we load react up into jsdom which means we don't need a browser, it then loads up. But clearly rather than just mounting this single component it is trying to run everything including my `router`

I shall read up more into this then.

Comment: So I need enzyme and then to not check the exact class but if it contains what I needed `  it('should have className', () => {    xpect(wrapper.first().prop('className'))      to.contain('indexAppContent');  })`

Answer (score 0):

When you unit test a component that renders a Route/Link/NavLink, you need to wrap it in a router.  See this example from the [api docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing):

```
// broken
test('it expands when the button is clicked', () => {
  render(
    <Sidebar/>
  )
  click(theButton)
  expect(theThingToBeOpen)
})

// fixed!
test('it expands when the button is clicked', () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Sidebar/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
  click(theButton)
  expect(theThingToBeOpen)
})
```

As far as checking for a specific class (as mentioned in your comment above), you should use the [hasClass](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hasClass.html) method.